# How do I call the functions for when I create the character class - Python - This is for a quiz game but using a tree traversal

Tags: python, function, class, oop, tree

#here I want to define the self.__tree but I am not sure how to do so, how would I create the tree?

```
  oijh0ij0ihoihihoihou
```

Comment: Why would you put get diffeculty to return points?

Comment: Why is `difficulty` stored in a variable called `self.__correct`? That seems to be confusing.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. What is the tree for? What is `Pikachu` for? What is a character class?

Comment: The tree stores the questions for each character e.g. Pikachu's tree contains one topic of questions and I want to define the questions that Pikachu will get in the Class Pikachu.